# Colour coding coordinates on a map

Tags: r, colors, coordinates

Hi I'm trying to colour code my coordinates points depending on the group, but can't seem to work it out. My code at the moment is:

```
ponymap <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(df$lon), lat = mean(df$lat)), zoom =14,
                  maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

ggmap(ponymap) +
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour="band"), size = 2, shape = 21) +`guides(fill="band", alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)`
```

If I add in `scale_color_manual(values=c("")` I don't get any changes to my map??

I have seven groups that need colour coding.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Which language/Framework?

Comment: I suggest that you provide a sample of data, but as a first guess you should remove the quotes around `"band"` in your `aes(colour = )` argument. Right now you are just setting the colour to a fixed `"band"` string, rather than the `band` variable in your data. In general, you should refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular the part about providing a reproducible problem.